# Return a single result in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

I am new to WCF and trying to make a simple CRUD service using Visual Studio 2012 and involving MSSQL stored procedures.

There is something I do not like about `Load` method. It is planned to return single entity by ID, but I have to use the `.First()` method because autogenerated `Goods.Context.cs` defines a result of `GoodsLoad` as `ObjectResult<GoodsLoad_Result>` instead of simple `GoodsLoad_Result`. How to make it autogenerated properly?

**Goods.Context.cs (auto generated)**

```
namespace StorehouseServer
{
    public partial class storehouseEntities : DbContext
    {
    //.............................................

        public virtual ObjectResult<GoodsLoad_Result> GoodsLoad(Nullable<int> iD)
        {
            var iDParameter = iD.HasValue ?
                new ObjectParameter("ID", iD) :
                new ObjectParameter("ID", typeof(int));

            return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<GoodsLoad_Result>("GoodsLoad", iDParameter);
        }
        //.............................................
    }
}
```

**IGoods.cs**

```
namespace StorehouseServer
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IGoods
    {
        [OperationContract]
        List<GoodsList_Result> List();
        [OperationContract]
        GoodsLoad_Result Load(int id);
    }
}
```

**Goods.svc.cs**

```
namespace StorehouseServer
{
    public class Goods : IGoods
    {
        public List<GoodsList_Result> List()
        {
            using (var db = new storehouseEntities())
            {
                return db.GoodsList().ToList();
            }
        }

        public GoodsLoad_Result Load(int id)
        {
            using (var db = new storehouseEntities())
            {
                return db.GoodsLoad(id).First();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ID is an unique identifier in database and a simple select:

```
SELECT * FROM Goods WHERE ID=@ID;
```

is assumed to return a single row.

Comment: Hmm... Is the "id" property defined as a unique identifier in the database? Because if it isn't, returning a list of matching items, which the code suggests, is the only valid option.

Comment: @Culme: I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

One of the fun things about EntityFramework is that you can use LINQ.

So you can do this:

```
db.GoodsLoad().Single(goods => goods.Id = id);
```

Or better yet, this:

```
db.GoodsLoad().Find(id);
```

Comment: Isn't this an overkill? I mean `Find` method instead of `First`. Theoretically `First` should work faster. And more: an application shouldn't have direct access to the tables. Only to stored procedures. This is my strong requirement.

Comment: This is where it gets hard.. It depends on the table structure, the indices, and so on and so forth of the table in the database. When you use a `First()` method, it **could** do a tablespace scan (*super* bad) rather than using an index. The `Find()` method uses the primary key (which in turn uses the index). And this is what I **think** you're trying to do, which is why I recommend it.

Comment: I am new to LINQ too. As I am thinking now, `First()` is like selecting a first item from an array (`arr[0]`) and it should not involve any indices. If stored procedure returns always a single row for certain, `First()` should be fast enough. Correct me if I'm wrong.